# using class base view facing a issue of reverse not found

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

i am using a class base d view for section.html in which i trying to implement add to cart functionality with the help of forms but after clicking add to car but it showing error

Reverse for 'section' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<subject_id>[0-9]+)/Sections/$']

here is my views.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class Sections(View):
    def post(self, request, subject_id):
        sections =request.POST.get('section')
        print(sections)
        return redirect('subjects:section')


    def get(self, request, subject_id):
        subject = get_object_or_404(Subject, pk=subject_id) # retrieve the subject 
        sections = subject.section.all() # get the sections related to the subject
        return render (request, 'sections.html',{"section_list" : sections })
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:subject_id>/Sections/', Sections.as_view(),name='section'),
]
```

my section.html

```
    <ul class="sec">
      {% for section in section_list %}
      <div class="card col-11">
        <div class="card-header">
        {{ section.title }}
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-about">{{ section.about_section }}</h5> <br>
          <i class="price fas fa-rupee-sign"> {{ section.price }}</i> <br> <br>
          <i class="icon text-white fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"> {{ section.teacher }}</i> 
          <i class="icon text-white fas fa-clock"> {{ section.content_duration}}</i>
          <i class="icon text-white fas fa-tags"> {{ section.subject.name }}</i>
          <form action="#" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
          <input hidden type="text" name="section" value="{{section.id}}">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="Add To Cart">
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

my section model is contected with another models name subject with foriegn key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify a `subject_id` to redirect since you have a `<int:subject_id>` in the path and the `get` method requires it.

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class Sections(View):
    def post(self, request, subject_id):
        sections =request.POST.get('section')
        print(sections)
        return redirect('subjects:section', subject_id=subject_id)
```